# How do I deploy an azure app to multiple regions?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have deployed my node js app to azure in the region west-us. However, my friends in other countries cannot connect to the server. How can I make sure that they are able to access the app too? Is there a setting that I need to change in my azure dashboard?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. As written, it's unclear what issue(s) you are running into, that's blocking your visitors. Multi-region deployment isn't a simple switch, as there are multiple components that make up an application. Also, you tagged this as `node.js` but without code, there's no connection to node.js in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you deploy in single region, still the users from different countries should be able to access your app with a public endpoint.

If your question is about setting up a secondary site, you need to create an appservice and use traffic manager to route the requests based on users region.

Comment: You've made the assumption that the OP used app service (vs a VM). And there are other challenges beyond a Web App, when considering multi-region deployments. But more importantly: there's simply not enough information in the question to start proposing an answer. It's currently unknown why there is no connectivity. This is why I posted a comment under the question asking for clarity, instead of an answer (as I think your commentary should be as well).